# Open program in another terminal window windows-solaris

Tags: solaris, editors, display

I am running Attachmate Reflection for UNIX and logging into my Solaris system. I then want to open a file with nedit but I get an error:

> NEdit: Can't open display

So, I type in

```
xhost +
```

and I get the following error:

```
xhost:  unable to open display ""
```

So I go a head and do:

```
setenv DISPLAY [Full Windows Computer Name]:0
```

and then I check my DISPLAY by:

```
xauth $DISPLAY
```

and I get back:

```
xauth: (argv):1:  unknown command "[Full Windows Computer Name]:0"
```

and at that point when I try to open the that file with nedit again I get:

```
Xlib: connection to "[Full Windows Computer Name]:0.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified
NEdit: Can't open display
```

Where **[Full Windows Computer Name]** is my windows PC computer name. Anyone has any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: xauth handles your local X11 cookies files - it doesn't use $DISPLAY or connect to a X server, so `xauth $DISPLAY` is both bad syntax and a bad test case.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong.

```
setenv DISPLAY [Full Windows Computer Name]:0
```

[Full Windows Computer Name] is not a computer name, use IP address and make it

```
setenv DISPLAY IPAddress:0
```

Comment: So if I do IPconfig in Command Prompt, which number should I use?

Comment: I have to add that I am on a network. And the [Full Windows Computer Name] included the domain name as well.

Comment: Please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/117075/edit) your Question with further information and output. If you don't understand the output of ipconfig put that in your question. You are sitting on your PC running reflection, you connect to solaris box, you want the IP that your solaris box can see of your PC.